# Creating lists of increasing length python

Tags: python, list

Hey i was wondering if anyone knew how to create a list of 10 lists of increasing length. The first list should be empty, i.e., `len(mylist[0]) == 0;` the second list should have one element, so `len(mylist[1]) == 1;` and so on. I have been trying to use `extend`,`append` and `insert` but to no avail

So far i have been able to create 10 lists with no elements

```
def mylists(x):    
    d = [[] for x in range(0,x)]
    return d

print (mylists(10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
super_list = []
for i in range(10):
    super_list.append(list(range(i))) # .append(range(i)) suffices for python2
```

You may want to tweak the ranges, depending on your desired outcome. 10 iterations of that will give you ten lists, like so:

```
[[],
 [0],
 [0, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

If you feel like doing it in a more [functional](https://xkcd.com/1270/) way, this will achieve the same result in Python 2:

```
map(range, range(10))
```

Or in Python 3:

```
list(map(lambda i: list(range(i)), range(10)))
```

Comment: Works for python2 only. Python3 will require a conversion to `list`.

Comment: You don't need the lambda. `map(range, range(10))` works fine.

Comment: Good comments, thanks. Lambda is still needed on Python 3 though, as it has the extra `list` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
print([[i]*i for i in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [[i for i in range(n)] for n in range(1,8,1)]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

For using method

```
>>> def test(n):
...     return [[i for i in range(m)] for m in range(1,n+2,1)]
... 
>>> 
>>> print test(5)
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```